# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Photo column type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In a web application I'm coding with Flask/SQLAlchemy, several of my models needs a "Photo" column type, which would handle storing the original image somewhere on the filesystem, and creating differents thumbnails size of the image. Ideally, I-d want something like:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    photo     = Column(Photo(root="/path/to/photos/", formats={
        "big"      : "800x600",
        "small"    : "400x300",
        "thumbnail": "100x75"
    }))
```

and then, I could access URI/URL of file like this:  model.photo.big  etc...

So, my question is: how to add setters/getters on the model.photo object so that I can access URIS/URLS with the mentionned syntax ? 
By the way, if someone has a good tutorial/resource (other than the official doc) on user defined types with SQLAlchemy, I would be grateful if he could share it.

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Flask-Upload](http://flask-uploads.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?
It seems to be exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer but i think it is more convenient to use a structure like described at below link for image thumbnails:

http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/1/26/pil-to-create-thumbnails-automatically-using-tag/#32aff91e05ba9985a49a76a4fb5338d7

Using a tag for creating thumbnails, you need to store only original image path in the db.

Comment: Finaly, I finished coding my Image field as described above. The tag approcach is interesting though.